# SDL, random color generator

Tags: c++, random, colors, sdl

My friend gave me a bit of code for my SDL program, all I know that it makes a random color but I have no idea how it works , here is the code

```
 int unsigned temp = 10101;//seed
    for(int y = 0;y < times;y++){
        temp = temp*(y+y+1);
        temp = (temp^(0xffffff))>>2;
        //printf("%x\n",temp);
        SDL_FillRect(sprite[y],NULL,temp);
        SDL_BlitSurface(sprite[y],&paste[y],rScreen(),NULL);
        }
```

My question is , How does this code work and how does it make a random color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is creating a "random RGB value" ranging from 0x000000 to 0xFFFFFF out of some amateur PRNG he invented.

I'll explain the code with comments:

This is the so called "seed". The initial value that will generate the pseudo-random sequence of values.

```
 int unsigned temp = 10101; //seed
```

then we got the for loop:

```
 for(int y = 0;y < times;y++)
 {
    temp = temp*(y+y+1);
    temp = (temp^(0xffffff))>>2;
```

each round your friend is trying to make complicated multiplications and sums to come up with a new temp value which is divided by 2 (the >>2 in the code above) and then masked with 0xFFFFFFF to get a value in the range of 0x000000 to 0xFFFFFFF (he wrongly used bitwise XOR ^ instead of bitwise AND &)

The resulting value is used as a RGB value for the SDL_FillRect() function.

```
    //printf("%x\n",temp);
    SDL_FillRect(sprite[y],NULL,temp);
    SDL_BlitSurface(sprite[y],&paste[y],rScreen(),NULL);
 }
```

Comment: "some amateur PRNG." - yeah, quite amateur, and his coding style is particularly poor.

Comment: why did "he wrongly used bitwise XOR ^ instead of bitwise AND &", the code works so is it not correct?

Comment: @Laggy: when it comes to PRNG is hard to say "it works" or "it doesn't work". We should talk about statistical distribution of the value produced. A good PRNG should approximate the pseudo random oracle (a mathematical model that spit out perfect random values). On a first look, it seems clear that the code provided is not a good PRNG. The bitwise AND would force the range from 0x000000 to 0xFFFFFF; instead, the XOR ^ is just flipping the bits of temp leaving it free to exceed the 0xFFFFFF limit. Maybe the division by 2 is just an attempt to keep the value in range.

Comment: Why don't you use some standard PRNG like rand() or such? You don't need quality randomness (you're not coding for cryptographic purposes) so rand() should do a great job with near-zero effort.

Comment: I didnt code this, it was my friend. It's good as it does the job, all I wanted to know is how it worked and now I know thanks for the anwsers

Answer (score 1):

The magic is in these four lines:

```
unsigned int temp = 10101; // seed - this seeds the random number generator

temp = temp * (y + y + 1); // this performs a multiplication with the number itself and y
// which is incremented upon each loop cycle
temp = (temp ^ 0xffffff) >> 2; // this reduces the generated random number
// in order it to be less than to 2 ^ 24
SDL_FillRect(sprite[y], NULL, temp); // and this fills the rectangle using `temp` as the color
// perhaps it interprets `temp` as an RGB 3-byte color value
```